# How to have Views Attachment show all results of View, including the ones on the next pager pages

Tags: views

We have a Drupal 9 View using a GeoField Map to display the results using an attachment. The problem is that we want the map to show all the results, not just the ones on the first page.

Currently, we have the pager set to 25 items per page so the map only shows those 25 instead of all of the results.

In addition to this, the map attachment is then replaced on the next page with the results from the next page.

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible for the pager in the Views attachment to "Display all items"?

Answer (score 0):

Attachment Views Display has several options that let you control its pagination in relation to the Display it is attached to.

Under **Attachment settings** make sure that the **Inherit contextual filters:** and **Inherit exposed filters:** are set to values that make sense in your case.

If you're using Contextual or regular Filters on your original (Page) Display, and you want the Attachment (Map) to always show all results no matter what, then those two options should be set to **No**.

This will make the map results independent from any narrowing down of the results that you or your users may apply on the Page (for example if you have Exposed Filters).

Then you can adjust **Pager** settings to be different from the original Display.

Under **Pager** settings on the Attachment Display opt to **Inherit pager: No**, and **override** the setting **Items to display:** to **Display all items** so it's different from the one you're using on the original Display (Page).